# How does Messenger refreshes itself in the background?

Tags: ios, background, apple-push-notifications

How do Messenger and other apps refresh themselves in the background regularly and display every single notification?

Is it a server that sends a signal to the app on a regular basis to refresh their data in the background?

Comment: do you read documentation? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1

Comment: I spent the last 3 days reading everything about APNs. I still don't get it. When I ask how I can do something similar to what Messenger or Tinder does people tell me it is impossible...

Comment: what is impossible? Apps can either receive push notifications or use background refresh and local notifications. Also those sort of apps will check with their server for any pending messages when they launch/return to the foreground.

Comment: Thank you @Paulw11. This means that all the data is in their servers and when something new shows up they then send a push to the device to update the user's data and display the notification?

Comment: Yes. How else could it work?  Devices may be switched off or offline, so you need a server to hold the messages

Comment: I am starting to get it. The issue I have with my app is that I am fetching the data from an API, not my own servers. So I guess I have to send pushes regularly and automatically to the device to tell the app to refresh in the background and display the notification if needed is this possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mostly applications use multiple ways to update notifications:

1. Send push notification, if in case you want to inform user about the activity.
2. Send silent push notification, if in case you don’t want to inform user that something happened in background. ( "content-available" : 1 )

IMPORTANT
Background update notifications are not meant as a way to keep your app awake in the background beyond quick refresh operations, nor are they meant for high priority updates. APNs treats background update notifications as low priority and may throttle their delivery altogether if the total number becomes excessive. The actual limits are dynamic and can change based on conditions, but try not to send more than a few notifications per hour.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html

But still most apps use this.

3. Run/schedule a background task to perform some action.